# Traverse DOM to determine status of parent. Return strings on conditions

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have:

```
var findParentByClassName = function(element, targetClass) {
if (element) {
    element.parentElement === null;
        console.log("No parent found");
} if else {
    element.parentElement !=== targetClass;
        console.log("No parent found with that class name");
} else {
    var currentParent = element.parentElement;
    while (currentParent.className !== targetClass && currentParent.className !== null) {
        currentParent = currentParent.parentElement;
    }
    return currentParent;
}
};
```

I need to be able to check for two other conditions:

1. Check to see if the provided "element" has a parent. If it does, send a string to the console.
2. If it does not find a parent with the provided "targetClass" name then have it return a different string to the console.

I'm assuming this would be done via an if - if-else - else function but for the life of me, I'm just not able to get it.

Comment: Did you try something out?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @Dekel - yes. My apologies. I pasted the wrong code in. I've since corrected. The code seems to work well in that everything displays properly on the page so long as I have the "if else" commented out. If that segment is live then I lose the table this references.

Comment: `} if else {`, `!===` ???

Comment: You will want to test the class of the `currentParent` inside the loop, not the `element`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this (code is explained under code snippet):

```
var findParentByClassName = function(elem, className)
{
  if(elem == null)
  {
    console.log("No elem");
  }
  else if(elem.parentNode == null)
  {
    console.log("No parent");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Found a parent, looking for an ancestor with the given class name");

    var ancestor = elem.parentNode;
    while(ancestor != null)
    {
      if(ancestor.classList.contains(className))
      {
        console.log("Found ancestor with correct classname");
        return parent;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("Could not find parent with correct class name.");
  return null;
};
```

First, you double check whether or not you were actually given an element. If not, we can do nothing.

Then, we use `else if` - not `if else` - to check if the element has a parent. If it does not, we can do nothing again.

Finally, our else branch is executed if we have an element with an ancestor. From this point, we can move up the DOM tree iteratively. If we find an element whose classList contains the className we were given, we have found a matching ancestor, and return it. Otherwise, we return null.

Note that this code finds an ancestor with a matching class name, which is not necessarily a direct parent. I'm assuming this is what you want based on your code.

Now, this becomes much easier if you're using jQuery:

```
var findParentByClassName = function(elem, className)
{
  return $(elem).closest("." + className);
};
```

The downside here is that you won't be able to log messages explaining
why no ancestor with the right class name could be found if one does not exist.

Here's how if-else if-else statements work:

```
if(condition)
{
  // code to execute if the condition is true
}
else if(condition2) // condition2 is only checked if the 1st one is false
{
  // code to run if condition2 is true
}
else if(condition3) // you can have 0 or more else if conditions
{
  // in practice, you can have as many as you want
  // there are limits, but you'll probably never reach them
  // unless you're trying to
}
else
{
  // code to execute if none of the conditions were true
}
```

Conditions are boolean expressions. These could be boolean values,
equality checks, greater than / less than, whether or not a variable
is null / undefined, so on and so forth.

I would recommend reading through a JavaScript tutorial for more information.